# Add some records to all eloquent query results

Tags: laravel, model

I have a table named food_portion like the following:

> id|food_id|name|gram_weight
>
> ---
>
> 1|102030|slice|183
>
> 2|102030|pie|183
>
> 3|102031|waffle|35
>
> ....

The table is complete, But some global portions are missing like gram/oz..
I wanted to write a query to add records for this portions but I'm thinking that its not a good choice because this portions have same value for all the foods.

> *|*|gr|1    (6000 records like this)
>
> *|*|oz|28   (and another 6000 like this)

So I'm looking for a way to modify my model (food_portion) so every time I execute some query using model get the the above records without having them physically in the database table, So my queries wouldn't be slow for no reason.

How can I do this. I tried to do this using global scope but I failed:

```
 protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('global_portions', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->orWhere( function($query)
        {
            //$query->where("food_id","*")->where("name","gr") ???
            // what should I write here?
        });
        });
    }
```

Bottom line is I want to prevent record repetition for every food.
I want to add two specific records to every query result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using accessor? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Thank You for your attention,Yes, I have many of them. But they are for adding columns not records

Comment: Sorry if I got you wrong, so you want to add more rows to the query result? eg if you queried 10 results, you will want to add another 100 to it so you get 110 records?

Comment: Just two records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are very close, check this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('global_portions', function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder) {
            $builder->union(DB::query()->select([
                DB::raw("\"*\" AS id"),
                DB::raw("\"*\" AS food_id"),
                DB::raw("\"gr\" AS name"),
                DB::raw("\"1\" AS gram_weight"),
            ]));
        });
    }
```

This is to add one record. To add more, simply chain more `union` functions, or edit the query inside.

Note: For Laravel 6.x use "boot" instead of "booted", and add a line `parent::boot();` before `addGlobalScope`